# Executing PGM command using the idb2 .NET provider

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to execute the PGM (IBM -Iseries) using IBMDB2 .NET provider. But I am always getting issues.

I tried using the ADO.NET provider (COM object) and some other ways, but I could not execute the PGM in i-series.
I am not sure whether it is possible to execute the PGM directly using the IBMDB2 .NET provider and ADO providers.

```
iDB2Connection icon = new iDB2Connection(strConnect);
                    iDB2Command command = icon.CreateCommand();
                    icon.Open();
                    command.CommandText = ($"CALL PGM(ABC/XYZ)PARM('1ASB         ''000013644')");

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can also use XMLSERVICE, which has various client interfaces, including .NET. I don't have personal experience with .NET but I'm sure Googling around will turn up something. Even more helpful would probably be joining the [midrange mailing lists](https://lists.midrange.com/) and/or the [IBMiOSS community on Ryver](https://ibmioss.ryver.com/application/signup/members/9tJsXDG7_iSSi1Q) and asking there.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the QCMDEXEC procedure from SQL however the quotes for parms are dicey to get straight.
**"Between the beginning quote and ending quote two quotes in a row result in a single quote in the string".**
  I'd suggest you get it working calling a simple program with no parms first.

```
CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('CALL PGM(ABC/XYZ)PARM(''1ASB         '' ''000013644'')')
```

/* the string is *call gpm(abc/zyc) parm('1ASB     '  '00013544')*